# I need to store and retrieve an group of form elements with each group being stored as an array of form elements

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a form that is made up of groups of elements that I store in a db table.
I use the table to build out the form pre populated with the data from the table I then can make any edits to any of the fields. If changes were indeed made then I reload the data to the table based on the form that was submitted. This works great for the most part by simply giving the name of the fields an array name like

```
<input  type="text" name="phone[]" value="123-123-1234"/>
```

for every element. When the form is submitted I read the arrays and load the data

The problem arises when I want to use a radio button which is normally stored that way as it needs to identify the options of the radio as an array turning one on and the other off and then storing the answer in the name given in the radio element so

```
YES<input  type="radio" name="choice[]" value="YES"/> NO<input  type="radio" name="choice[]" value="NO"/>
```

give you the option for each iteration. So when I store the data from all these groups I need the individual options for each of the choice arrays to match up with the other elements in each group of elements

I tried doing something like this with not much luck

```
        echo'   Yes <input type="radio" name="type'.$c.'[]" value="IT" checked="checked"/>';
    echo'   No <input type="radio" name="type'.$c.'[]" value="NON"/>';
```

inside of a loop that iterates $c so I end up with type1[], type2[] type3[] etc where the number matches the element in the phone array as well so phone[$c] is in the same group as the choice of YES or NO store in type$c[0] this works great in the form as each group radio button element turns to yes or no independently of the others without the type.$c it combines them all into a single block of radio buttons with only a single option being able to be selected.

Maybe I am overthinking this and just so focused on this approach that I can not see a simpler one. If I am indeed missing the KISS solution please do not bash me too much and possibly supply me with the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well I found the resolution I was overthinking it
The answer was to use this structure in the radio element of the form

```
    echo'   Yes <input type="radio" name="type['.$c.'][]" value="IT" checked="checked"/>';
echo'   No <input type="radio" name="type['.$c.'][]" value="NON"/>';
```

and then when parsing the forms parameters read the radio value like this

$choice=$type[$c][0]---while incrementing $c

so I was close